# Spring Integration Zookeeper - Am I Currently leader

Tags: java, spring-integration, apache-zookeeper, apache-curator

Have a Spring Integration 4.3.8 app deployed on multiple Tomcat instances and the app uses `org.springframework.integration:spring-integration-zookeeper:4.3.8.RELEASE` to run the multiple instances of the app in a cluster where only one at a time is ever elected as leader.

Question is, what is the simplest way to query from within the app whether I am currently the leader or not? Can I get this info via an available Curator/Zookeeper API? Or do I need to create an event listener of some sort?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope you use `LeaderInitiator`.

When it is granted the leader role, an `OnGrantedEvent` is emitted.
That even has `Context` property. And that one, in turn, has `isLeader()` state.

you can store this object for future use and check is `isLeader()`  whenever you need.

Since version `5.0` `LeaderInitiator` provides direct access to the context:

```
/**
 * The context of the initiator or null if not running.
 * @return the context (or null if not running)
 * @since 5.0
 */
public Context getContext() {
    if (this.leaderSelector == null) {
        return NULL_CONTEXT;
    }
    return this.context;
}
```

Comment: You could also call `isRunning()` on one of the endpoints; it should only be true if you are the leader.

Comment: @GaryRussell, our endpoints have been overridden as we have business cases where we want some endpoints to not start even when the deployment becomes leader. In fact, this is why we are looking for a way of knowing whether we are leader or not so that we can call `super.start()` on overriden endpoints only if `hasLeadership = true`. Hence why querying `isRunning()` on the endpoint does not work for us in this case.

Comment: OK, @PonderMuse! I wonder if my answer is appropriate for your use-case.

Comment: @Artem, where is version 5.0 available? We are currently using version 4.3.8 which is the latest release in Maven. Is version 5.0 in a snapshot repository somewhere? Getting access to the `CuratorContext` and calling `isLeader()` on it should do the trick.

Comment: The latest one is `M3`: https://spring.io/blog/2017/04/05/spring-integration-5-0-milestone-3-available. But as I said: you handle `OnGranted/OnRevoked` events to obtain that `Context` for future purpose. If there is no event, then no `Context` and, therefore, you are not leader. It is like a workaround until `5.0` GA if that. We may consider to backport that `getContext()` though... Just in case you really can't come up with the solution without that, fee free to raise an appropriate JIRA: https://jira.spring.io/browse/INT

Comment: @ArtemBilan, understood. We have now overridden endpoints which implement `ApplicationListener<AbstractLeaderEvent>` and using those events' `.getContext().isLeader()` to keep track of whether we are leader or not. Have run some test scenarios in a two node cluster and we are now getting the behaviour we need using `4.3.8`.